# Why our changes inside the HTML web site which is hosted inside IIS are not showing to public users

Tags: html, iis, caching, windows-server-2019, wwwroot

We are facing this weird behaviour, where we have a Windows server 2019 with IIS. And we hosted an HTML web site inside C:\inetpub\wwwroot. Now we did some modifications to the HTML pages, mainly showing additional html elements and hiding some elements.

Now if we click on the HTML page inside the IIS, the changes will be shown locally, but on the public web site accessed from the internet by public users, the changes will not be shown. Now the weird thing is that I did an IIS reset on the server, and some of the changes start to appear for the public users for couple of minutes then the modification will no more show.

So, I checked the pages again, and I can see that our modification to the HTML is still there, but are not affecting the public users. Any advice on this please? Could it be a caching issue? Although we have waited for more then 12 hours without any luck.
Thanks

Comment: I would suggest you modify your site locally and then rehost the site in the IIS. If you are able to see the changes in the browser on the local machine then I don't think there is some issue with the IIS. It could be a Cache issue. you could try to visit the site in incognito mode or try pressing the `CTRL + F5` key to clear the cache. Further, I will suggest you visit the site in multiple browsers to check the results. If possible, try to visit the site from different machines to see whether other machines display the modified content.

Comment: Static files can be cached in various places, browser, proxy, IIS output caches and more, and the cache behaviors at each locations are controlled separately. So if you experience issues right now, the suggestion is to learn what happen exactly for typical users and what are the impacts from each cache locations. Before knowing clearly those things, no much can be discussed.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT I tried clearing the browser cache and use another devices.. seems the caching is happening on the server in a way or another and not on the client/browser side

Comment: @LexLi thanks, i checked the IIS cache folder and it is empty + i cleared the browser cache.. so what else i can do? thanks

Comment: You need a lot more data to be collected on the wire than merely the browser and the server. Find your network administrators to assist as they know more about what tools/utilities might help collect the packets in various locations.

Comment: Have you tried to recycle the Application Pool? If not, you could try it. further, I would like to confirm that it is a pure HTML site? If not, please provide more information about your site. Further, please inform us, what are the changes that are not getting reflected?

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT it is a pure HTML web site.. all pages are .html and the first page is index.html